# "array out of range"on using iMAonArray

Tags: arrays, mql4

I'd like to ask a bit help: I want to integrate a rule to my EA but I cannot   make an array properly.. The rule would be "if the SMA of RSI on higher TF is above/under blabla..."

so here is my code:

```
   double MA;  
   double RSIBuf[];
   double MaBuf[];

ArrayResize(RSIBuf,0);
int counted_bars=IndicatorCounted();
int limit = Bars-counted_bars-1;
for(int i=limit; i>=0; i--)
{
RSIBuf[i] = (iRSI(NULL,higherTF,RSIPeriod,0,i)); 
MaBuf[i] = iMAOnArray(RSIBuf,higherTF,RSI_SMA,0,0,i);
}
MA = MaBuf[0];
```

...

```
direction Trend=NEUTRAL;

if(MA>RSI_Up )        Trend=UP;
```

the MT4 says its an error on RSIBuf[] Line

Where I made wrong? thanks for helping..
wicha

Comment: probably you can show the full MCVE example of the indicator to help you. Or you may check `MACD` indicator that uses another implementation of the `iMAOnArray` function

Comment: thanks for the tip, but i didn't find any useful stuff in the MACD source code. The rule  i want to integrate is a simple SMA is put on the RSI line on a higher TF. If the value the SMA shows is above 50 then up,  else down. Thats all

Comment: J.P. gave you the correct answer. remove `ArrayResize(RSIBuf,0);` and make sure you have two dynamic buffers using `SetIndexBuffer` function

Answer (score 0):

You were saying it is an EA, but you're using an indicator code.

In an Indicator, you would want to declare buffers as buffers:

```
IndicatorBuffers(2);    //Allocate memory for buffers

double RSIBuf[];   //indicator buffers
double MaBuf[];

// Bind the array and allocated memory to an actual double-array dynamic buffer
SetIndexBuffer(0, RSIBuf);
SetIndexBuffer(1, MaBuf);

int counted_bars=IndicatorCounted();
int limit = Bars-counted_bars-1;

for(int i=limit; i>=0; i--)
{
   RSIBuf[i] = iRSI(NULL,higherTF,RSIPeriod,0,i); 
   MaBuf[i] = iMAOnArray(RSIBuf,higherTF,RSI_SMA,0,0,i);
}
MA = MaBuf[0];
```

If it was in an EA, you would have to allocate enough memory in advance, like this:

```
int maxBars = TerminalInfoInteger(TERMINAL_MAXBARS);
double RSIBuf[maxBars];
double MaBuf[maxBar];
```

And then you carry on as usual.